# how to get an arbitrary file from an HTTP request in grails

Tags: rest, groovy, grails

I am trying to set up a web service in grails that can accept a file. How do I get the file from the request?

I am testing this with something like

```
curl -d somefile.tar http://localhost:8080/MyWebS/fileWS
```

and my method looks like the following:

```
def index = {
    switch(request.method){
    case "POST":
    render "Ingesting file\n"
    request.each {
    println("--> " + it)
    }
    def uploadedFile = request.getFile() //<--this is the line that doesnt work..what should it be?
    File f=new File('c:/dev/newfile.tar');
    uploadedFile.transferTo(f);

    break
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786329/upload-a-file-to-a-grails-project-and-then-inserted-to-database

Comment: Its not quite a duplicate. I am trying to set this up to be tested with curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you try

```
curl -F file=@somefile.tar http://localhost:8080/MyWebS/fileWS
```

And then on the grails side

```
def uploadedFile = request.getFile( 'file' )
```

Comment: So something else that would call my webservice (say from some C# project) would just have to call my method with a parameter called file?

Comment: If you're just streaming data to the request, you probably just want to read it from request.inputStream