# getting newlines right when posting file to grails app

Tags: rest, grails

I have to make a massive import to a data base. Lets say around 100k rows.

The user has to be able to handle the file with the rows, like a csv. With one data per line.

As in the company I have to use rest apis for every thing I want to make an api in grails that you can post a file into and the api handle the import job.

So making something like

```
curl -X POST -d @file http://apiurl/process-file
```

I'm trying to achieve this in grails.

First I had to add filters in order to get more than one inputstream from the request, in orther to get the raw content of the file.

The problem that I have now is that it doesn't recognize the newlines in the file.

I put an app [here that reproduce the case](https://github.com/dnoseda/PostFile).

I wan't to know what's the problem and how to achieve this the simplest way possible.

I would thank any advice or pointer.

Comment: Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875076/how-to-get-an-arbitrary-file-from-an-http-request-in-grails) help? Once you have the file you can easily read lines with a reader or you can use the [csv plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/csv) to read each line.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this, the problem was the way I call curl

This is the right way:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @file http://apiurl/process-file
```

So `curl` doesn't format the body before posting.